# In a vuejs form, how can I only grab the data of the visible elements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use v-if on my vuejs html elements to dictate when they should appear. They appear or disappear based on other form inputs. Here is the problem: first, element A is visible, and I set its value to true. Then, I change input B which hides element A. Then, I submit the form, and grab the data using this.$data. This object value unfortunately still shows element A as true. I would like it that element A, since it is hidden, to not show up in my data object at all. How can I make this happen? I suppose I can loop through this.$data, however, how do I check if a property is hidden?

Comment: Can you show the code used?

Comment: I just need someone who understands vuejs to answer; they wouldn't need to see any code.

Comment: I know Vue. However, when you ask you should do everything it's in your hands to help others understand your question. If it possible, provide an example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do this without manually control the data that is going to be sent in your request.

You should be able to create a valid object to your request by checking your current component state instead of using it directly, like

```
const validForm = {
  b: this.form.b
}
if (!this.form.b) {
  validForm.a = this.form.a
}
axios.post(url, validForm)
```

Anyway, if you still want your raw state, you can watch the values changing and then deleting / adding them to your state using `$set` and `$delete` to keep them reactive. You'll have use `v-if` and not `v-show` to hide elements to prevent runtime warnings.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        a: false,
        b: false
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.form));
    }
  },
  watch: {
    "form.b"() {
      if (this.form.b) {
        this.$delete(this.form, "a");
      } else {
        this.$set(this.form, "a", false);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<form id="app" @submit.prevent="submit">
  <span v-if="!form.b">
    <input id="inputA" type="checkbox" v-model="form.a">
    <label for="inputA">Input A</label>
  </span>
  <input id="inputB" type="checkbox" v-model="form.b">
  <label for="inputB">Input B</label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```